Facebook logs me out when I login on another device
Yesterday, I've reviewed on Facebook the devices I'm logged in, and did a cleanup.
Then, I logged in into my remaining current devices: Mac (Brave browser) and Android (Facebook app). As expected, I had to use password and Authenticator, all fine.
What's weird now: Anytime I log into the Mac, I get logged out from the Android, and vice versa.
So I assume there must be some setting "allow/disallow being logged into multiple devices". But I can't find it. Where I looked:

On Password and security, I see "Saved login". I states that my login info is saved on this device.

Yet on Where you're logged in, I always only see the current device (and I'm getting logged out from the other).


Any idea what I could try else?

Can you confirm you aren't using private browsing or set up your browser to clear your history every time it closes.

Yes, can confirm. Just logged in on a fresh Google Chrome. It kicked me out from Brave. Then logged in on Google Chrome Private window. It kicked me out from the regular Chrome window.
